Identifying an older electrical breaker
Wondering if anyone knows what brand/model breaker box this is and what year its from approximately? Is it original? (this is on the exterior of a single family house built in 1947 in southern california) I'm trying to understand if they updated the electrical in this house or not. I know within the past 20 years they added a subpanel at the garage but doubt they upgraded the main breaker at that point. The inside of the house has some outlets without grounds.



Not 1947 vintage... Pics are too fuzzy, but I'm sure you can read some of the lettering on the individual breakers, ie BR20, that'll positively identify.

Digression, but that four wide service disconnect is... Interesting?

@keshlam Not that unusual at all. See for example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-200-Amp-2-Pole-120-Volt-240-Volt-Mini-Branch-Circuit-Breaker-Allows-Up-to-Lifetime-Warranty-HOM2200BB/328587954

Ah. Always more to learn.

Can you get us a photo of the label on the inside of the door please, as well as closeups of some of the breakers?

As an aside, I believe the doorbell transformer in the bottom of the panel is a code violation. It looks like the low-voltage wires aren’t isolated from line voltage in the box.

Look close at the main breaker, it'll say something like Murray or ITE. Either one will mean Siemens.  Certainly not 1947 vintage. More 1997.
